# What happens to static variables in Android 4.2 for Multi-User environment

Tags: java, android, static-variables

The way Google said how multi user will work is that: "Each user on a device has his or her own set of accounts, apps, system settings, files, and any other user-associated data."

I think/believe that this is done by using different UIDs.

If that is true, for apps that means it has to kill the existing app first and run it as a different UID. This means that classes will be reloaded and static variables will be created again for the new user.

And above is true, then static variables should be gone.

Can someone confirm that?

Comment: What makes you think that an App has to be restarted in order to run it under a different user ID? Is see no reason why there can't be 2 processes of the same App with different UIDs...

Comment: If two processes of the same app are running, the one that started later in time is essentially a "restart" (though technically not correct) with different uid for our purposes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` variables are associated with classloader+class where they are defined. So, pretty sure that they will be gone (or) not accessible for second user login.

I am not sure about UIDs (or) what approach is used to identify unique user.